# 'Mushed' meaning

Tags: meaning, verbs, meaning-in-context

I've been translating the song by Johnny Horton, *North to Alaska* and was stuck on the word ***mushed***:

> He talked to his team of huskies as he **mushed** on through the snow

Searching through the dictionaries gave me nothing about it.

Doesn't it mean 'crawling' or just 'going?'  Or, maybe, there's a mistake?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Mush* is the traditional cry for encouraging sled dogs—“Mush, you huskies!”

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mush) conjectures

> first recorded 1862, as *mouche*, perhaps altered from French *marchons!* "advance!" (imperative of *marcher* "to march)"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for that dictionary, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it seems to mean 'just going', as the AHD notes.

[mush](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mush) 2  (mŭsh)

> v. mushed, mush·ing, mush·es
>   v.intr.
>   To travel, especially over snow with a dogsled.

Comment: Yes, I've just wanted more accurate meaning of it. If I write "going" it would be flat and pale.

Comment: I would have to say that this definition is wrong: *mush* means *to travel using a dogsled*. Adding *especially* is like saying *to drive* means *to travel, especially in a motorized vehicle*. You can't use *drive* for airplanes. You can't use *mush* for cars.

Comment: 'Mushing is a general term for a sport or transport method powered by dogs. It includes carting, pulka, scootering, sled dog racing, skijoring, freighting, and weight pulling. More specifically, it implies the use of one or more dogs to pull a sled on snow or a rig on dry land.' And please look at the article at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushing) –the 1909 musher photo is priceless.